# How do install a Adobe flash player in Ubuntu 13.10 for Chromium

Tags: flash, system-installation

I have just downloaded `install_flash_player_linux.11_x86_tar.gz` from the Adobe website. How do I install this package or any other package not found in the Ubuntu Software Center.
I have used `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.
Rebooted and flash is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after enabling the restricted repository but before running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the flash player package as part of Ubuntu restricted extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This will install Flash player, along with proprietary video codecs, fonts, etc.

Make sure these reposotories are enabled in 'Software & Updates': 
[image: In 'Software & Updates', enable all software under 'Ubuntu Software' & 'Downloadable form the internet']

Comment: I have tried all you suggested and flash dose not work

Comment: have you tried other browsers? Chrome, Firefox, etc?

Comment: This does not work for Firefox 29

Answer (score -1):

try flash player in software Center and install it , it works for me . on chromium and firefox both.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome has flash preinstalled.

**For firefox and other browsers**
Extract the file you downloaded and place the file into /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins

or just use `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer -y`